# how to make widget receive mouse release event when context menu appears

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5

On Ubuntu20.04, I can't have the widget receive the mouse release event when context menu appears while Windows can receive. My pyqt version is 5.15.2.

I've considered sending a mouse release event manually, but I don't know which systems will receive the mouse release event when context menu appears, and doing so may cause repeated release events. Is there any better solution?

```py
# coding:utf-8
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMenu, QLabel


class Menu(QMenu):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.addAction('action 1')
        self.addAction('action 2')

    def showEvent(self, e):
        print('show context menu')
        super().showEvent(e)


class Widget(QLabel):

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        print('mouse press, button:', e.button())
        super().mousePressEvent(e)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        print('mouse release, button:', e.button())
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(e)


class Demo(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.widget = Widget('Click Me', self)
        self.widget.move(175, 180)
        self.resize(400, 400)

    def contextMenuEvent(self, e):
        menu = Menu(self)
        menu.exec(e.globalPos())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Demo()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Since you're not handling the right mouse button, can't you just ignore it?

Comment: Since you're not handling the right mouse button, can't you just ignore it?

Comment: @musicamante This is a minimum demo, I actually handle the mouse release event

Comment: Do you need to handle the *right* mouse button release, for a widget that has a parent that will actually show the context menu? Can you please clarify the widget structure and requirements for your program?

Comment: @musicamante In the mouse press event, I will move children in Widget, and then in the mouse release event, I will use animation to move these children to their original positions.

Comment: Please answer *all* questions that are asked, and be more *detailed*.

Comment: @musicamante I just need Widget to receive mouse release event. There's no need to care about other details.

Comment: Yes, there ***is***. Because if you want to be able to move the widget with the *left* button, then you do *not* need to care about the context menu, since you can just *ignore* events from the *right button*. If we ask about details, there is *always* a reason, so please answer what is being requested if you want to be helped.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you for your advice. Whether it's the left or right button, I need to move the children of Widget in the mouse press event, and then move back when the mouse is released. In this way, the visual effect of the interface will be better.

Comment: So, it's some sort of offset similar to the button text on Windows, that slightly moves the text when it's pressed. Are you completely sure that you want this effect *also* for right mouse button, since you're actually implementing the context menu (which should "override" that event) in the parent?

Comment: @musicamante Yes, the effect is very similar to that of windows. It will be strange if the animation is not displayed when mouse is released. You can see the animation in  readme of [https://github.com/zhiyiYo/Groove](https://github.com/zhiyiYo/Groove).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule is that the context menu event is fired when the right mouse buttons is released on Windows and pressed on Linux.

To avoid inconsistency and have a generic behavior that just ignores the OS and always does the same, you can set an internal flag and check it whenever is required: since the context menu event might take precedence, call a function from *both* mouse press and context menu.

Remember that:

- if you don't want to handle the context menu event and want it to propagate to the parent (like in your case), the event *must* be ignored; if you override `contextMenuEvent` this must be done explicitly either with `event.ignore()` or by calling the base implementation, assuming that it does *not* accept the event;
- QLabel might handle the event if the text interaction flag supports mouse/keyboard navigation (to allow the clipboard menu);
- context menu event can also be triggered by the menu-key on the keyboard, so you should ensure that its [`reason()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcontextmenuevent.html#Reason-enum) is `Mouse`; this is not actually required if the function that does the "unpress" part always check for the above flag (and it should), but it's still good practice to check for the reason for completeness and consistency;

```py
class Widget(QLabel):
    _isPressed = False
    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        print('mouse press, button:', e.button())
        super().mousePressEvent(e)
        self._isPressed = True

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(e)
        self.unpress()

    def contextMenuEvent(self, e):
        super().contextMenuEvent(e)
        # or, alternatively:
        e.ignore()

        if e.reason() == e.Mouse:
            self.unpress()

    def unpress(self):
        if not self._isPressed:
            return
        self._isPressed = True
        # do whatever you need
```